# Docker Container computation time

Tags: docker, resources, containers

I am working on a project to allocate tasks to the containers. Since my major is not Computer science, I am not familiar with the mathematical theory behind that.
The question which I am going to ask is regarding the computation time of Docker containers.
I am copying a part of an article that confuses me.

```
Delay(t) = lambda(t) / C_max

where C_max is the capacity of resources allocated to the container. The lambda be the
 mean of a Poisson Process of the requests arrival.
```

Now, I have several questions:

1. What is the unit of lambda and C_max if the resources allocated to this container are Processing resources? Would it be a cycle per sec?
2. Can more than one task be allocated to a container at the same time or we need a buffer to store future tasks to be processed?

Answer (score 1):

Question 2:
Yes, more than one task can be executed in a container at the same time. A container can have multiple processes inside it. But for ease of working with and reasoning about often people just try to put a single process inside a container.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about the formula? You know how it works and what are the units?

Comment: @AlirezaHosseini You're welcome. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the formula. Could you please upvote my answer so I can get some reputation?